# Teaching: Field, Class & Package Relationships

Tags: theory

In general I think I can convey most programming related concepts quite well.
Yet, I still find it hard to summarise the relationship between Fields, Classes and Packages.

**How do You summarise "Fields", "Classes" and "Packages" and "Their Relationship" ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem since I taught C, C++, and Java.
Here is what I do:

First, I keep packages separately and explain them in the end.

Ideally, in my opinion, students should first learn about ADTs, preferably in C. They have the struct, they have the separate operations on it. Fields are then simply the "slots" in the struct and you can even show the memory layout to demonstrate it. Functions are separate entities that operate on those structs.

You then make the transition to classes, methods, and fields and show that in essence (barring inheritance and some anecdotes) they are in many ways syntactic sugar for ADTs.

If you need, you can then teach object layouts, inheritance, and virtual tables (in my experience it helps students understand inheritance better to see the memory layout).

Finally you get to the topic of how to organize classes together. If you teach C++, you don't really have packages but you can explain namespaces and discuss organization and separate compilation.

If you are in Java, then you just explain that these are collections of classes in the same namespace, that have special access rules and show them. The package system in Java is kind of broken anyway so I usually go through patterns (e.g., separating a UI package from the C).

So in summary: Classes form the basis for objects that are a memory arrangement of several fields and associated methods that operate on them. Packages are collections of classes that have one more access restriction mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The way I describe it is:

- Objects are collections of slots, slots holding data are fields, slots holding code are methods. Public slots are on the outside of the object, private slots are on the inside. Methods should be mostly public because an object offers services to clients, fields should be private so clients don't know how the services work. Fields are therefore an implementation detail of objects.
- Class names need to be unique, so that you can combine your code with third party libraries. Simple/short class names are insufficient, since there are probably thousands of classes called 'List', 'Customer' etc... Hence classes are placed in packages to create longer, harder to duplicate names. Only a subset of the classes in the package need to be visible to clients, hence the two access levels of public and default. This allows a package to function as a library.

So fields are an implementation detail of objects, whose classes live in packages to guarantee unique names and provide library-like modularity.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the age of the person you're trying to explain it to, there's a simple analogy that can be used:  tax forms.  A tax form (such as the 1040EZ, for instance) is like a class, and each space to be filled in on the form is a field of the form.  The tax form even contains instructions on what to be done with the information in the fields, just as a class includes member functions to be performed on the data in the fields.  And just as a complete set of tax forms includes not just the main tax form, but others that may need to be filled out (additional schedules, for example) so a package contains not just the main classes but other classes it may need to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

Fields are variables that belong to the class, or to object instances of the class.  The difference between a local variable and a field is that fields have a broader scope.

Classes are templates for user-defined data types.  Classes are more advanced than the primitive data types because they have both state and behavior.

Packages are used to group classes and to resolve potential naming conflicts.  With multiple developers and publicly available code libraries it's very likely that some of us will name our classes the same (Math, LinkedList, FileUtils, etc.).  Having a unique package name prefixing the class name allows the compiler (and other developers) to determine which class you intend to use.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, you tackled OO programming without mentioning objects.  I think that may be your problem.

Here's what I use.

Objects are things.  They have attributes (measurements, states of being, etc.) Attributes can be called fields.  [I often use things I find in the classroom -- cups, markers, hats, coats, etc., to illustrate this.]

Objects also engage in behaviors, called methods, method functions or operations.

The features (attributes and operations, fields and methods, whatever) of an object provide a way to classify objects.

The features that are common to a class of objects is -- well -- can be collected into a class definition.  A class  definition describes the attributes and methods of the objects that are members of the class.

A package is a collection of class definitions.   While -- ideally -- the classes in a package have something in common, that isn't a requirement and isn't a helpful distinction.